I have an old external HDD with a broken connector port… Is there any way to fix it?
I have an external HDD which I bought in the early to mid 2010s. (It has a date of "03 AUG 2012" on it.) It's a 1TB, Western Digital My Passport brand; the P/N is "WD10TMVW - 11ZSMS5". The S/N is "WXB1A7236164".
I got it out of storage today and have tried connecting it to my laptop, but I got an error message about parameters - I thought that maybe the drive was dead, so I opened the case and took it out, but it appears that the problem is the place where the drive connects to the cable. I've included an image of the port: it looks very bent.
Is there a way that I can fix the port; and if not, then is there any way that I can replace the port? The drive has some files on it which are sentimental to me.


Update: I downloaded and installed CrystalDiskInfo - I had never heard if that all before, so thank you for mentioning it. However, when I selected the HDD in the list of drives, it said "not responding" for quite a while, and then this information popped up, which I've included in the two new screenshots.
I had hoped that the drive was okay once I saw the connector, but now I'm not sure.







Are you talking about the micro-B port? That doesn't look bent – that's more or less the standard shape for "USB 3.0 micro-B"?

stop asking is there a way? and start asking what is the way?


“I have an old external HDD with a broken connector port… Is there any way to fix it?”

Why do you assume that the drive has a broken connector port? The port on that drive looks fine. That is a standard USB 3.0 micro-B port with utterly no damage.
If the surrounding case is broken, you can just get a basic USB A or USB C to micro-B port cable and that should work. See picture below of an example of a USB A to micro-B cable.

That said, if you were able to get CrystalDiskInfo to work, but then as you describe the following:

However, when I selected the HDD in the list of drives, it said "not responding" for quite a while, and then this information popped up, which I've included in the two new screenshots.

That points to the drive itself failing. Why? I don’t know and cannot say. But a logical error like that has 100% nothing to do with the physical damage to the connector you describe.
I would recommend you mounting the drive, if at all possible, and copying the contents to a new/working drive.

Your issue has nothing to do with the connector; it's the drive itself that is failing. The screenshots clearly show your drive has reallocated sectors, which means the drive is doomed, and that the issue can only get worse going forward.
Any attempt at uselessly trying to read the disk would only exhacerbate the issue, so if you care about the data on the drive you should stop trying to read the drive's contents.
The only way out of this (besides resorting to expensive data recovery services) is to try and image the drive using some sort of recovery software. It might be a lenghty process, and it might not work at all, depending on the conditions of the drive. But if that works, after that, you'll have the option to either:

Mount the image;
Write the image back to a healthy drive and mount the drive.

Note that choosing an appropriate recovery software is crucial here. Simple cloning tools that just read drives block by block won't cut it here, because those will likely just get stuck on the first unreadable sector while reading the drive sequentially. You need something "clever" (or configurable) that can choose to discard a sector / limit itself to read each sector N times at most before giving up and going forward, at the cost of a sector.
On Linux, I'd use ddrescue to image the drive. You could run ddrescue basically from whatever Live Linux distro with ddrescue available in its repositories (on a Ubuntu desktop Live, you could install ddrescue by running sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt install gddrescue).
I'm unfamiliar with Windows solutions.
